# seg fault in terminal when trying to read file with merge sort

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read a text file named data and then sort it using mergesort. I run the command through the terminal by typing *mergeSort < data*, 
but get a segmentation fault. The data text file is just a list of random numbers.

The code for mergesort is as follows:

```
#include "mySort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 50

void mySort(int array[], unsigned int first, unsigned int last)
{
int mid;
int i;
int j;
int k;
mid = 0; 
i = 0; 
j = 0; 
k = 0; 
int Larr[MAX], Rarr[MAX];

if (first < last) 
{
    mid = (first - last - 1)/2;
    mySort(array, first, mid);
    mySort(array, mid+1, last);



    for(i = 0; i < (mid - (first+1)); i++)
        Larr[i] = array[i + first -1];
    for(j = 0; j < (last - mid); j++)
        Rarr[j] = array[mid + j];

    Larr[mid - first + 1] = 9999999;
    Rarr[last - mid + 1] = 9999999;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for(k = first; k <= last; k++)
        {
        if (myCompare(Larr[i], Rarr[j]) < 0) 
            {
            myCopy(&Larr[i],&array[k]);
            i++;
            }
        else
            {
            myCopy(&Rarr[j],&array[k]);
            j++;
            }
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: You're almost certainly writing beyond the end of one of your arrays. Look for cases where your array indices might be out of range.

Comment: Tracking down errors (such as segmentation faults) is an important part of the process of learning to program in courses such as the one you're taking.  Try running a smaller version of your program -- say, only the part (which you forgot to show us) that reads the input -- and see whether it succeeds.  Then, if that works, move on to reading the input and running one loop of the sort.  Etc ...

Comment: I suggest creating a `main()` program with a fixed-size array with say 14 elements in it, and sort that. This should segregate the sort code from the input code, so if you don't crash with this, there's a chance that the problem is in the input code.  Make sure you've got a `void dump_array(char const *tag, int *arr, int n)` function that dumps the content of the given tag (so you can identify different calls to the function) and the array and number of elements.  Use `fflush(stdout)` at the end of the function.  Call it at appropriate points in your code to see what's going on.

Comment: Since you're on Linux, you might benefit from using `malloc()` to create arrays (and `free()` to release them), and then using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to validate that you are not abusing memory.  Make sure you compile with the debug flag on; you will then get remarkably accurate reports on what the problem is if you are abusing memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile with `gcc -g` to ensure you have debugging enabled.
2. Set ulimit. `ulimit -c unlimited`. This ensures a core will be made when the segfault happens.
3. Run your program.
4. Run `gdb ./mergeSort core.XXX`. When gdb starts up, use the 'bt' command to get a backtrace and see where things went wrong. Run gdb from the same dir the source files are in.

Check out these links on debugging too.

http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Debug.html

http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/

Comment: And `-Wall -Wextra`...to make sure that the mistakes the compiler can spot are being spotted.

Comment: _#0  0x0000000000400824 in mySort (array=Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff7678af68
) at mergeSort.c:7
#1  0x0000000000400899 in mySort (array=0x7fff77326f50, first=0, last=1431655765)
    at mergeSort.c:21_ 
These are the errors I get. How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Look at that value for `last`. I am willing to best that is a bogus value. Possibly when you compute the value of `mid`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include two useful links about debugging programs. Good luck!